# Is 'calculatable' a spoken mistake?

Tags: pronunciation

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/tpmdcJYnAyQ?t=1095)

> how many of these are
> actually **calculatable** from others ...

I didn't find this word in [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=calculatabe)

Is this a spoken mistake? which should be **calculable**

Comment: See also [Evaluable vs. Evaluatable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304948/evaluable-vs-evaluatable) or [calculatable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calculatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ‘calculatable’ was intended: this will be accepted as valid but non-ideal spoken English by most hearers.

‘Calculable’ would be better, but there is a reason why your lecturer used the alternative.

There is a tendency to use -able as a suffix to completely unmodified verbs in spoken English.

Language is a statistical entity.  Informal language is even more probabilistic and less rule-bound.

One might expect a lecture to be more formal in nature and not less, but that is not necessarily so.

When delivered from prepared notes or a long hand script a lecture may be quite formal, true.

And yet extemporaneous speech—though it may adhere to a certain high register—is more taxing for the speaker to generate continuously while still following  some set of grammatical (or other) rules exactly.

There is little conscious deliberation possible in a monologue (as opposed to a conversation of multiple parties) and the thoughts will be expressed in common patterns that are freely available to the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

The suffix *-able* is a productive suffix in Modern English, it can be appended to an enormous number of words without altering the the root word. For instance, *[envisageable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/258202/106592)* sounds very natural even though it's not present in reliable online dictionaries.

In some cases, it does alter the root word as in *calculable*, but generally, it doesn't. The lecturer said *calculatable* probably by analogy with other words whose pronunciations don't get altered.

It's now present in some online dictionaries such as [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calculatable), [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/calculatable), [WordSense.Eu](https://www.wordsense.eu/calculatable/), [Glosbe](https://glosbe.com/en/en/calculatable).