# Is "envisageable" a legitimate English adjective?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, suffixes

I am wondering If I can say (self-made example)

Given the growth rate of the job market, a better future is envisageable.

I searched about it and it looks, it is basically a French term. So, I am not very sure about its usage in English.

Comment: It's possible that it's a valid construction, but it's not a great-sounding word. How about "foreseeable"?

Comment: @user34258 Thank you for the suggestion, I was just wondering how it would sound.

Comment: How it might be used is envisageable to me

Comment: Why stop there? "Given the growth rate of the job market, the envisageability of a better future is increasing" :)

Comment: @user34258 "Forsee" implies you can *predict* something may happen. "Envisage" implies you can *imagine* something may happen. Different meanings.

Comment: @alephzero You're right, *imaginable* probably a better choice.

Answer (score 10):

Of course, you can. There are loads of verbs in English that can be adjectivised. When I saw the word *envisageable* in your question, it didn't strike me as strange.

[We append the suffix *-able* to verbs](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/forming-adjectives/) and give them the meaning *able to be (verb)ed*.

Therefore, *envisageable* is a legitimate word and it means *able to be envisaged*. Most native speakers will understand what you mean by *envisageable* even if they haven't heard it before.

And most adjectives are *verbifiable*. :)

However, we do not change the pronunciation of the consonant preceding the suffix *-able*. For example, you cannot remove the silent e from *envisage* when appending the suffix *-able* because it changes the pronunciation of the preceding consonant. So *envisagable* would be incorrect.

But if the removal of the silent e doesn't change the pronunciation, you can remove the e. So *trade* + *able* -> *tradeable* but when you remove the e, it doesn't change the pronunciation so *tradable* is also correct.

See [Google Ngram results for 'envisageable'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=envisageable&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenvisageable%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cenvisageable%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Envisageable in Google Ngram Viewer]

Most results are from French sources but there are English sources as well.

Comment: See, I've just made up ***verbifiable*** from the verb *verbify* and the suffix *-able*.

Comment: There are lots of thing you can eat but don't taste very good, and if you serve them to guests you won't be considered a good host. If I can continue with my metaphor, "envisageable" is just like that.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, You're right but if I read the question correctly, it's asking *is this thing edible or not* and doesn't ask about its *taste* :)

Comment: You are correct, but as this is a site for people who are learning the English language, and like any living language English is more than the just the rules -- there are lots of nuances and there is the sort of reaction you are likely to elicit when using a particular phrase. I think we help the questioner best when we also help them with those aspects.

Comment: I lived in France for so long I am genuinely annoyed when a word that now comes very naturally to me in English - like envisageable - gets the red squiggly. English, can be made to include all of French though, so I shall continue using it! Now if only I had the courage to spell "connexion" how it should be spelt (and was still a possible variant in the 1933 Shorter Oxford!)...